# Codes not allowing proper arithmetic operation on javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current codes are not allowing me to properly display the operators. At this time I am not able to display an operator after an initial calculation. For example, if I do this '9+2' then press '='. I will get a result but if I press an operator like '*' the display will only show the operator without the number. Looking at my current code what am I missing? Please advise.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var shouldbeClear = false;
  //create variable to store input from user to calculate later
  var inputs = [''];
  //create string to store current input string
  var totalString;
  //create operators array for validation without the .
  var operators1 = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
  var operators2 = ['.'];
  //numbers for validation
  var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  function getValue(value) {
    if (operators2.includes(inputs[inputs.length - 1]) === true && value === '.') {
      alert('STOP & RESTART!!!');
    } else if (inputs.length === 1 && operators1.includes(value) === false) {
      inputs.push(value);
    } else if (operators1.includes(inputs[inputs.length - 1]) === false) {
      inputs.push(value);
    } else if (nums.includes(Number(value))) {
      inputs.push(value);
    }
    update();

  }

  function update() {
    totalString = inputs.join('');
    $('#display').html(totalString);
  }



  function getTotal() {
    shouldbeClear = true;
    totalString = inputs.join('');
    $('#display').html(eval(totalString));
    var result = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
    inputs = [];
    inputs[0] = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
      inputs[i + 1] = result[i];

    }
    update();

  }

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    if (this.id === 'deleteAll') {
      inputs = ['0'];
      update();

    } else if (this.id === 'backSpace') {
      inputs.pop();
      update();
    } else if (this.id === 'total') {
      getTotal();

    } else {
      if (inputs[inputs.length - 1].indexOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.') === -1) {
        if (shouldBeCleared){
        shouldBeCleared = false;
        inputs=[''];
        update();

        getValue(this.id);

      } else {
        getValue(this.id);


      }
    }

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="calcOutput">
    <span id="display">Enter Some Number...</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center" id="calculator">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn3d" id="deleteAll">AC</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn3d" id="backSpace">CE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="/">/</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="*">*</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="-">-</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="+">+</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id=".">.</button><br>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn3d bigButton" id="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn3d bigButton" id="total">=</button><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no javascript in your post

Comment: Please update your question and include the relevant `javascript` If possible create a snippet for people to run. Also explain what you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: Dear silkshocker its really a pitty how you treated this issue. It doesn't make sense to ask for a specific problem and after getting an appropriate answer implement the answer to your own question asking for another issue. Its just unfair towards the person who took the effort to help you which was @unamata-sanatarai in this case with [his answer that solved your original request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46749561/3931192). Therefor I had to downvote your question.

Comment: I strongly recommend to make a [rollback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) to your original post. If you do so I will upvote again of course. If you need help with this feel free to leave a commet. regards

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable which will inform the calculator whether it should clear everything.

I called the variable `shouldBeCleared`

Each time you click on `=` shouldBeCleared is set to true.

Then if you click on any NUMBER, check if `shouldBeCleared` is set to true, clear your inputs array and update().

As follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var shouldBeCleared = false; 
  //create variable to store input from user to calculate later
  var inputs = [''];
  //create string to store current input string
  var totalString;
  //create operators array for validation without the .
  var operators1 = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
  var operators2 = ['.'];
  //numbers for validation
  var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  function getValue(value) {
    if (operators2.includes(inputs[inputs.length - 1]) === true && value === '.') {
      alert('STOP & RESTART!!!');
    } else if (inputs.length === 1 && operators1.includes(value) === false) {
      inputs.push(value);
    } else if (operators1.includes(inputs[inputs.length - 1]) === false) {
      inputs.push(value);
    } else if (nums.includes(Number(value))) {
      inputs.push(value);
    }
    update();

  }

  function update() {
    totalString = inputs.join('');
    $('#display').html(totalString);
  }



  function getTotal() {
    shouldBeCleared = true;
    totalString = inputs.join('');
    $('#display').html(eval(totalString));
    var result = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
    inputs = [];
    inputs[0] = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length - 1; i++) {
      inputs[i + 1] = result[i];

    }
    update();

  }

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    if (this.id === 'deleteAll') {
      inputs = ['0'];
      update();

    } else if (this.id === 'backSpace') {
      inputs.pop();
      update();
    } else if (this.id === 'total') {
      getTotal();

    } else {
      if (inputs[inputs.length - 1].indexOf('+', '-', '/', '*', '.') === -1) {
      
        if (shouldBeCleared){
            shouldBeCleared = false;
            inputs=[''];
            update();
        }
        getValue(this.id);

      } else {
        getValue(this.id);


      }
    }

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="calcOutput">
    <span id="display">Enter Some Number...</span>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center" id="calculator">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn3d" id="deleteAll">AC</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn3d" id="backSpace">CE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="/">/</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="*">*</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="9">9</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="-">-</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="6">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id="+">+</button><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn3d" id="3">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn3d" id=".">.</button><br>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn3d bigButton" id="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn3d bigButton" id="total">=</button><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this code messes up the operators. Instead of keeping the value for addition or whatever, it erases it and you end up with an operator without a number in front of it.

Comment: your original code allows for that operation. I only took care of the erasing part after having clicked `=`. Might I suggest another question to solve the remaining issues?

Comment: Just to add another opinion: I think Unamata Sanatarai is right here. @silkshocker your formulation was precise and straigth forward: **"I want it to reset and display only the new number pressed after the previous calculation is done."**. This is exactly what Unamata Sanatarais solution achieves. So I would mark his answer as accepted and ask another question for the new issue. Its a win win also because if your next question performs as well as this one you will gain extra rep. Anyway +1 for both question and answer from me! regards :)

Comment: Thank you. I will edit the question to ask for the address of the other issue.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit the question to ask for the address of the other issue.